# How to make javascript load first time everytime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Hello I have been experiencing a common issue regarding loading external Javascript, I use a gulp development environment which is obviously used to compress the files such as HTML and JS.

When I hard refresh the browser such as Google Chrome or Firefox by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> the javascript doesn't always seem to load and would thus require a refresh of the page again, it isn't consistent but when testing outside of the dev environment I experience the same issue.

I have also used the basic line of code that waits for the entire page to be downloaded first before loading being the following;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {}
```

Just to clarify, I have tried other methods as well but haven't received any different results other than the inconsistency of loading the JS.

I am using the jQuery library within my project but it is the only js library being used.

Some other methods I have tried to negate the issue was by placing the script tags for calling in the jQuery and the js file at the start of the HTML page being in the head and also just before the closing tag of the html tag.

Just to also clarify, here are the script tags I am using to call in the jQuery and the js file.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>

<script src="assets/js/functions.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any console errors? Also, what resources are loading for the page in the network inspector?

Comment: add a unique hash to your assets...

Comment: You could save your JavaScript files as `.php` instead, and use that `src`. Then they won't be cached.

Comment: @damanptyltd I am not seeing any errors within the dev console and have checked through both the dev environment and build environment to see if any console errors were appearing. The resources that I would be loading are jQuery and my own functions file, so it would be a jQuery cdn and then my functions.js file. Then one css file and images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue through trial and error; the issue was that the jQuery would occasionally load a little after the functions javascript has loaded, this would lead to functions being created using jQuery would any jQuery library to reference.

The issue was that I used the 'async' property within the jQuery script import to allow the content after the script tag to load while the script tag itself is still loading.

Answer (score 0):

Open DevTools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) goto Network tab and check Disable cache checkbox. Now, every time you will refresh page, all scripts will be refreshed.

Additionaly, If you want scripts to be refreshed at any device/browser, you have to add to script url additional parameters. Ex:

```
<script src="app.js?v=1.2"></script>
```

Every time when you will change `?v=1.3` browser will redownload script.

Comment: I included in my original question that I press Ctrl + F5, this ensures that everytime the page loads that all assets are being deleted and seen as loading for the first time. When I am out of the development environment and testing the build environment which would be the final product to upload to a web server; the JS files do not load first time and require a refresh before loading, this isn't suitable for when users go to use the website as JS functionality wouldn't work.

Comment: Then add some additional parameters for include. I have edited my unswer.

Comment: Yes thank you for your answer, however, when I would attempt to load the project for the first time on a computer that has never seen the files before; the issue would still occur of not loading the javascript the first time and times not even the second time. When I check the console for any possible errors; there are none which makes the situation confusing and a little frustrating.